# How to get a city's current time independent of user's current time in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem in JS which I couldn't find an exact answer online (even on StackOverFlow). Basically, I have created 3 clocks to show current times of New York, Sydney and Tokyo. I use Date()  function then converting it toLocaleString to get exact time of those cities but the problem is that if my system's time is incorrect then those clocks will also show incorrect time.
Is there an easy way so that I get the local time of NY, Sydney and Tokyo without using Date()?

My current code is here:

```
    var countryTimeZone = new Date(now.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo' }));
    var time = countryTimeZone.getHours() * 3600 +
        countryTimeZone.getMinutes() * 60 +
        countryTimeZone.getSeconds() * 1 +
        countryTimeZone.getMilliseconds() / 1000
    rotate(secondElement, time)
    rotate(minuteElement, time / 60)
    rotate(hourElement, time / 60 / 12)
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: You could always scrape it out of a page.. such as https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toJSON() method of the Date Object. It will always return the string converted to UTC time, which you can then use to define new date. Refer to below link

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I am really new to JS, and looked at the link you've sent but couldn't figure it out. Can you please help me with this? Thanks